# Android app which will print a toast whenever it receives a system broadcast on Battery status

Tags: java, android

```
*
```

1. *I run this program and got this error?  What is wrong?  How do you fix it?

   ```
        C:\Users\NAME\GetBatteryInfoApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:2:
    AAPT: error: resource dimen/activity_vertical_margin (aka
    com.java2blog.android.getbatteryinfoapp:dimen/activity_vertical_margin)
    not found.


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.java2blog.android.getbatteryinfoapp.MainActivity">
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewBatteryStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Current Battery Status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonBatteryStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewBatteryStatus"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Click here to Get battery Info" />
        </RelativeLayout>*
   ```

- 

Answer (score 0):

```
     MainActivity.java
    package com.java2blog.android.getbatteryinfoapp; //package
        com.java2blog.checkbatterystatusapp; import
        androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
        
        import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity; import
        android.content.BroadcastReceiver; import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent; import android.content.IntentFilter;
        import android.os.BatteryManager; import android.os.Bundle; import
        android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import
        android.widget.TextView; //import
        com.java2blog.checkbatterystatusapp.R;
        
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            //public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            TextView textview;
            Button button;
            IntentFilter intentfilter;
            int deviceStatus;
            String currentBatteryStatus="Battery Info";
            int batteryLevel;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBatteryStatus);
                textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewBatteryStatus);
        
                intentfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(broadcastreceiver,intentfilter);
        
                    }
                });
        
            }
        
            private BroadcastReceiver broadcastreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
                    deviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,-1);
                    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                    int batteryLevel=(int)(((float)level / (float)scale) * 100.0f);
        
                    if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING){
        
                        textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");
        
                    }
        
                    if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING){
        
                        textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Discharging at "+batteryLevel+" %");
        
                    }
        
                    if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL){
        
                        textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+"= Battery Full at "+batteryLevel+" %");
        
                    }
        
                    if(deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN){
        
                        textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Unknown at "+batteryLevel+" %");
                    }
        
        
                    if (deviceStatus == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING){
        
                        textview.setText(currentBatteryStatus+" = Not Charging at "+batteryLevel+" %");
        
                    }
        
                }
            }; }
```